# Generically modify struct fields using reflection in golang

Tags: go

Below is a method which uses reflect package to modify fields of a struct ,this works for a specific struct type

```
func modify(obj Car) interface{} {
        ty := reflect.TypeOf(obj)
        for i := 0; i < ty.NumField(); i++ {
            rval := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(&obj))
            field := rval.Field(i)
            fieldType := field.Kind()
    
            switch fieldType {
            case reflect.String:
                field.SetString("")
            case reflect.Int:
                field.SetInt(0)
            case reflect.Ptr:
                field.Set(reflect.ValueOf(nil))
    
            }
        }
        return obj
    }
```

modifying the signature to

```
func modify(obj interface{}) interface{} {
```

results in
panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Field on interface Value

at line

```
 field := rval.Field(i)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/pGfKtIg5RUp
It works with the signature

```
func modify(obj Car) interface{} {
```

https://go.dev/play/p/31Oh6WLmlGP

Why is the compile time type modifying the behaviour ?
The goal here is to mask certain fields based on struct tags .It could wrap an endpoint and the input and output to the method being wrapped could be struct or pointer so in above case both calls should work

```
modify(car)

modify(&car)
```

Comment: Because now `obj` is an interface type and interface types do not have fields. You have to add `.Elem()` to go from interface to value stored in interface.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/VKvAmVV_Ik-

Comment: @mkopriva In your example you modified the call to modify(&car) , I needed it to work both for car and &car .Added the version in answer which is working .The purpose was to wrap the method and log it's input and output with some fields masked

Comment: @Volker Thanks ,though it's little counter-intuitive that the compile time type in method signature affects ValueOf(obj) as the object being passed is same

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works for both value and pointer types

```
func modify(obj interface{}) interface{} {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(obj)
    trv := reflect.TypeOf(obj)
    value := reflect.New(rv.Type())
    if rv.Kind() == reflect.Pointer {
        rv = reflect.ValueOf(obj).Elem()
        trv = reflect.TypeOf(obj).Elem()
        value = reflect.New(rv.Type())
    }
    for i := 0; i < rv.NumField(); i++ {
        field := rv.Field(i)
        fieldType := field.Kind()
        v := value.Elem().Field(i)
        tag, _ := trv.Field(i).Tag.Lookup("es")
        if len(tag) != 0 {

            switch fieldType {
            case reflect.String:
                v.SetString(tag)
            case reflect.Int:
                v.SetInt(0)
            case reflect.Ptr:
                v.Set(reflect.ValueOf(nil))

            }
        } else {
            v.Set(field)
        }
    }

    return value
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/C1pqw_UbPcG